# Ruby on Rails 4 select multiple

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form that creates new users. I am trying to add a drop down option to select permission levels. I want to be able to select multiple permission levels per user.

This is my view, I added `{:multiple => true}` :

```
<%= f.label :permission, "Permission Level" %>
<%= f.select :permission, [ ["Read Only", "read"], ["IP Voice Telephony", "ip_voice"], ["IP Video Telephony", "ip_video_telephony"], ["Enterprise Gateways", "enterprise_gateways"], ["Consumer ATAs", "consumer_atas"], ["IP PBX", "ip_pbx"], ["Master of All", "all"] ], {prompt: "Select Permission Level"}, {:multiple => true}, class: "input-lg" %>
```

My controller, I added `:permission => []` :

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :admin, :permission => [])
end
```

The error I get for my view, f.select:

```
wrong number of arguments (5 for 2..4)
```

How do you make a select multiple for Rails 4?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`class` and `multiple` are both part of `html_options`, so they should go together in a single hash.

Change

```
<%= f.select :permission, [ ["Read Only", "read"], ["IP Voice Telephony", "ip_voice"], ["IP Video Telephony", "ip_video_telephony"], ["Enterprise Gateways", "enterprise_gateways"], ["Consumer ATAs", "consumer_atas"], ["IP PBX", "ip_pbx"], ["Master of All", "all"] ], {prompt: "Select Permission Level"},
{:multiple => true}, class: "input-lg" %>
```

To

```
<%= f.select :permission, [ ["Read Only", "read"], ["IP Voice Telephony", "ip_voice"], ["IP Video Telephony", "ip_video_telephony"], ["Enterprise Gateways", "enterprise_gateways"], ["Consumer ATAs", "consumer_atas"], ["IP PBX", "ip_pbx"], ["Master of All", "all"] ], {prompt: "Select Permission Level"},
{:multiple => true, class: "input-lg"} %>
```

Right now you are passing them separately. So, the argument count for `select` method is becoming 5 when it should be 4. Hence, the error.

Comment: +1 Explanation, Wow, can you please give a reference, I was having a hard time finding one.

Comment: You can check http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select and http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select

Comment: Well, I thought I was first. Refresh your page. :D

Comment: Actually @KirtiThorat beat me by a few seconds so please accept her answer.

Comment: Kirti, how will the multiple option version be saved in the db? I can't find a good read on it.

Answer (score 6):

Your option for :class is not in the hash for html_options:

```
{:multiple => true}, class: "input-lg"
```

should be

```
{:multiple => true, class: "input-lg"}
```

Comment: When you use the helpers in a form builder it's a little confusing because they take one fewer option than the non-wrapped versions, since the form builder itself gives the object.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't test it so far but the error message is pretty straight forward, you are trying to use the #select method using 5 params and it accepts at most 4 params, reading the API it seems that you should provide the 'class' attribute in the same hash you have provided the 'multiple' as they both are html_options.

Try to use it like this:

```
<%= f.select :permission,
             [ ["Read Only", "read"],
               ["IP Voice Telephony", "ip_voice"],
               ["IP Video Telephony", "ip_video_telephony"],
               ["Enterprise Gateways", "enterprise_gateways"],
               ["Consumer ATAs", "consumer_atas"],
               ["IP PBX", "ip_pbx"],
               ["Master of All", "all"] ],
             {prompt: "Select Permission Level"},
             {multiple: true, class: "input-lg"} %>
```

It would also be good to have that permissions array decoupled to another place. Perhaps it will help to maintain.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select