# Unpermitted params customer_ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

Super simple, dumb thing, which I can't figure out for more, than an hour now:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(customer_ids: []) # pg array column
end
```

My form:

```
= f.select :customer_ids,
    options_from_collection_for_select(customers, 'id', 'name', user.customer_ids),
    { include_blank: 'Select customer', multiple: true, size: 15 },
    class: 'form-control'
```

And while updating user I'm getting

```
Unpermitted parameter: customer_ids
```

How the heck in the world is that possible?

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"oCkUEi2pNajM0ydHUH2w6iYIq5eKjfCY5ig9U2qDTXxMqECCgQ2Dn9YtqkMqXlTmLl5q/OO8x23o/P50SnmgUg==", "user"=>{"customer_ids"=>"84"}, "commit"=>"Assign selected customer to user", "id"=>"2"}
```

Comment: `...permit(customer_ids: [])` is the right syntax. Something else is going on in your code. I suggest you look elsewhere. The other thing I can think of is that, for some reason, the column isn't being recognised as an array.

Comment: try like this `def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit( :customer_ids => [] ) # pg array column
end`

Comment: @Mohamad where? I mean I debugged it and all looks good, but it either says unpermitted params, or, when I change to `permit(:customer_ids)` it just does not update the `customer_ids`

Comment: I think in that case `.permit(:customer_ids)` should work

Comment: add `{}` in the form field  `options_from_collection_for_select(customers, 'id', 'name', user.customer_ids), {},{ include_blank: 'Select customer', multiple: true, size: 15 },
    class: 'form-control'` . it should work. try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form isn't sending in the `customer_ids` parameters as an array.

```
"user"=>{"customer_ids"=>"84"}
```

This is why. It should be (notice the square brackets):

```
"user"=>{"customer_ids"=>"[84]"}
```

If you declare the param as an array, it should be posted as an array. This is likely an issue in your form.

Usually, I would use checkboxes for something like this, but this depends on your user interface. Here's something similar I have done in the past.

```
= f.collection_check_boxes :customers, customers, :id, :name do |cb|
  = cb.label
    span.pull-right = cb.check_box
```

Look at the collection form helpers in Rails. A multiselect should work, but I have not used one this way.

Comment: He is not able to access it through `.permit(:customer_ids)` either

Comment: Got run to get my son to school. I'll look at it when I get back. Otherwise my wife will kill me :D

Comment: @AndreyDeineko This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253449/ruby-on-rails-4-select-multiple

Comment: @Mohamed, nevermind, I figured it out. Thanks again for pointing out! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `select` tag like this

```
= f.select(:customer_ids, customers.collect { |c| [ c.name, c.id ] }, 
                          { prompt: "Select Customer"}, 
                          { multiple: true, size: 5, class: 'form-control' })
```

Comment: this would still not send an array in params, unfortunately

Comment: Are you still getting ids as string in the params?

Comment: this was my initial problem and I still do

Comment: Then until you get the solution, as a workaround you can do something like `customer_ids = user_params[:customer_ids].split(' ')` after changing your `permit()` method to `.permit(:customer_ids)`